# Excel macro to transpose specific cells from row to column

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I am working with data from an image analysis software which exports data in the following way :

[image: SampleImage]

In every case, two empty rows separate the Image name from the different annotations put on the Image itself. The next Image is separated from the last annotation by three empty rows. 
All annotations are refered to by their number and consist of a measurement, its unit and a comment about which kind of measurement it is. However, this disposition is not practical. It would be much easier to manage the data if it were displayed like this:

[image: SampleImage2]

In the form of a table with "Annotation", "Comment", "Value" and "Unit" as headers, with all information about the annotation in the same row. So far I've tried to transpose the data manually, but this takes way too long when many images are involved. I also tried to use the macro recorder to automate the process, but it doesn't work since it uses fixed positions in the worksheet. Moreover, all Images don't possess the same number of annotations.

Could anyone help me create a macro to do such a thing? I've started dabbling with the VBA code recently, but this is way out of my league.

Comment: Does it always contain `Image Name` in Column A for every image?

Comment: Yes, every image begins with Image Name in Column A, I made sure to have at least one common element for all images in order for a macro to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro will do the work except for the lines between records, 3 lines will remain. The main point is that the record should start with "Image Name" (the check is case-insensitive). You can adjust it later to match the requirements.

```
Sub ReorderImageRecords()
Dim cnt As Long, curidx As Long

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 cnt = 0
 If Left(LCase(Cells(i, 1)), 10) = "image name" Then
   Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
   Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
   curidx = i
   Cells(curidx + 1, 1) = "Annotation"
   Cells(curidx + 1, 2) = "Comment"
   Cells(curidx + 1, 3) = "Value"
   Cells(curidx + 1, 4) = "Unit"
   While Not IsEmpty(Cells(curidx + cnt + 2, 2))
     cnt = cnt + 1
     Cells(curidx + cnt + 1, 2) = Cells(curidx + cnt + 2, 3)
     Cells(curidx + cnt + 2, 2).EntireRow.Delete
   Wend
   i = i + cnt + 1
 End If
Next i

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

And here is an optimized version without `curidx` and with the code to remove extra lines in between image records:

```
Sub ReorderImageRecords()
Dim cnt As Long, i As Long

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 cnt = 0
 If i > 1 Then ' If it is not the 1st row
   If Application.CountA(Cells(i - 1, 1).EntireRow) = 0 Then
     Cells(i - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete ' Delete if the whole preceding row is empty
   End If
   If Application.CountA(Cells(i - 1, 1).EntireRow) = 0 Then
     Cells(i - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete ' Repeat row removal
   End If
 End If
 If Left(LCase(Cells(i, 1)), 10) = "image name" Then ' We found an image record start
   Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete ' We delete unnecessary blank rows
   Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete ' Repeat removal
   Cells(i + 1, 1) = "Annotation"   ' Insert headers
   Cells(i + 1, 2) = "Comment"
   Cells(i + 1, 3) = "Value"
   Cells(i + 1, 4) = "Unit"
   While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i + cnt + 2, 2)) ' If we are still within one and the same record
     cnt = cnt + 1
     Cells(i + cnt + 1, 2) = Cells(i + cnt + 2, 3) ' Copy comment
     Cells(i + cnt + 2, 2).EntireRow.Delete        ' Remove row with comment
   Wend
   i = i + cnt + 1 ' Increment row index to the current value
 End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I'll have to try it at work on a bigger file to make sure, but it works perfectly. Just out of curiosity, why is the first EntireRow.Delete line doubled? I'd love to understand the process of the macro to get to learn more functions and terms.

Comment: @Zerkaden: In your specifications, there are 2 blank lines after image name row. So, I repeat the line in the code, as there is no built-in method to remove a specific number of rows at a stretch. Actually, this macro can be further optimized, as now, I see that `curidx` is not necessary. Also, I know of a way to remove extra lines in between the records. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I already mentioned I'll post a possible solution so here it goes (although kinda late).

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lr As Long, r As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheet1 'source worksheet; change to suit
        lr = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = .Range("A1:D" & lr)
        r.Replace "Length", "": r.AutoFilter 1, "<>"
        r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheet4.Range("A1")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        r.AutoFilter 2, "<>"
        r.Offset(0, 2).Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
            Sheet4.Range("E1")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    With Sheet4 'output worksheet; change to suit
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B1:B" & lr).Copy: .Range("E1:E" & lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , True
        .Range("E1:E" & lr).Replace "Attribute Name", "Comment"
        .Range("E1:E" & lr).Cut .Range("B1")
        .Range("C1:C" & lr).AutoFilter 1, "<>"
        .Range("D2:D" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Replace "", "Unit"
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This will work if the data is as consistent as what you've posted above.
Also result will be something like this (no space between Image name).
Also it needs an `output worksheet` (in above case it is Sheet4). HTH.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! However, it doesn't work as well as the one above : the first issue is that when I export data from the imaging software the sheet1 always has a different name. I changed it to Sheet1 to make sure it would work, but now the VBA tells me that the Sheet4 variable is undefined. I tried to specifically create a Sheet4 to check if it would change anything, but the issue stays the same. Anyway, the first suggestion works perfectly, but I wanted to give you feedback on yours. Thanks again : )